# How can @ColumnTransformer use the value inside application.yaml

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

How can i put the encription_key and encription_type in the @ColumnTransformer Annotation `read` or `write` parameter from application.yaml

```
@ColumnTransformer(read = "convert_from(decrypt(decode(phone,'hex'), {encription key}, {encription method}),'utf8')", write = "encode(encrypt(convert_to(?,'utf8'),{encription key}, {encription method}),'hex')")
```

What i did is

get the value from application.yaml and put it in

```
    @Value("${codec.iv}")
    private final static String key="";
```

Use Database Custom function to return bytea::encription_key - it is works but not want to
HardCoding

I also see that using postgres.conf - not want.

What i want to do is

get the key and encription_method from external files(like application.yaml etc…)

Comment: Hi , Have you got solution ? If yes ,it would be great help if you share with us. I couldn't find any solution in the web. thank you